# Round corner TD not Working

Tags: html, css

below code for round css dont know why isnt its working

its working only on background color if given; 
 but not the border

the border code is on the same line 
`style=" border :  1px  solid  #D6D6D6;`
and round css below

```css
.Round {
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; position: fixed; top: 0;      right: 0;     left: 0;">
  <tr height="20%" style="background-color:#3D4552;">
    <th colspan="3" class="shadow">
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" style="top: 15px; left: 92px; position: absolute; height: 55px; width: 10%;">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/CasePROLogoweb.jpg" runat="server" />
      </asp:Panel>


    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr height="10%">
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="45%">
    <td width="30%"></td>
    <td width="40%" style=" border :  1px  solid  #D6D6D6; " class="Round">' Here is the class for round
    </td>
    <td width="30%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="25%">
    <td colspan="3" colspan="8" align="center" style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 40pt; color: #FFFFFF">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's working but not showing because of `border-collapse:collapse` given to `<table>`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the border-collapse on the table to separate and the border to 0 (to actually see it properly)

```
<table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="border-collapse:separate; position: fixed; top: 0;      right: 0;     left: 0;">
```

Comment: this worked with round corner but now what happened is there some gap between body and table

Comment: Will you be putting rounded corners on adjacent cells. If not, just change it back to `border-collapse: collapse`. Let me know if that's not what you want. Cheers!